# extracting a group of values based on the values in another data table using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Imagine I have a LARGE table (table1) that looks similar to that of below.

TABLE 1:

```
YEAR     MODEL    MAKE      ORDERCODE  COLOR

2001      BMW     328i      FAE        GREEN
2001      BMW     328i      SDC        BLACK
2001      LEXUS   LS430     ASD        PURPLE
2001      LEXUS   IS300     ASD        BLACK
2001      LEXUS   GS300h    YUK        BLACK
2001      LEXUS   GS300h    HNY        BLUE
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    ASF        PURPLE
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    FAS        BROWN
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    YUI        RED
2002      LEXUS   IS250d    ZXC        ORANGE
2002      LEXUS   IS250d    ASE        BLUE
```

I have another data frame that has another make (lets say it's an Accord, with BLACK, BLUE, PURPLE and RED), so it looks something like this:

TABLE2:

```
MAKE     COLOR
Accord   BLACK
Accord   RED
Accord   BLUE
Accord   PURPLE
```

I am trying to look up all cars in TABLE1 that have ALL of the colors in table2.  I've tried using dplyr `table1 %>% filter(COLOR %in% table2$COLOR)`, but I am returned any row that has at least one of the given colors i'm looking for.  I would like to return the rows for the MAKE of car that has the colors I'm specifying.  So my result would be something like this:

DESIRED RESULT:

```
2001      LEXUS   GS300h    YUK        BLACK
2001      LEXUS   GS300h    HNY        BLUE
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    ASF        PURPLE
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    FAS        BROWN
2002      LEXUS   GS300h    YUI        RED
```

Comment: so from table2 the make column isn't important. You just want to check all color values from table 2 , in table 1 for every model. did I understand correct?

Comment: Haven't tested, but you can modify your code to `table1 %>% group_by(MODEL, MAKE) %>% filter(all(COLOR %in% table2$COLOR))`

Comment: @Yolo.  The make column in Table2 is what i'm most interested in.  I'm wanting to find the Make in table2 that is the most similar to the make in table1.  I'm defining similarity by matching color.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried that, but I ended up only getting one row.  In my real dataset, I only have 1 key (Make), so grouping by Model doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested the code previously, try this `table1 %>% group_by(MODEL, MAKE) %>% filter(all(table2$COLOR %in% COLOR))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The pipe function is `%>%` not `%<%`.) Needed to create a grouping in TABLE1 based on both make and model,  and to reverse the "direction" of the `%in%` operation within the test, and to add a logical `all` operation. The question is whether *all* the colors in the second table are present within the colors restricted to a single grouping.

```
TABLE1 %>% group_by(MODEL, MAKE) %>% filter(all(TABLE2$COLOR %in% COLOR))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   MODEL, MAKE [1]
   YEAR MODEL MAKE   ORDERCODE COLOR 
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> 
1  2001 LEXUS GS300h YUK       BLACK 
2  2001 LEXUS GS300h HNY       BLUE  
3  2002 LEXUS GS300h ASF       PURPLE
4  2002 LEXUS GS300h FAS       BROWN 
5  2002 LEXUS GS300h YUI       RED
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the most similar, we are going to find the total color matches per model, and finally we select the model with highest color matches.

**dplyr**

```
df %>% 
    group_by(MODEL,MAKE) %>% 
    mutate(slr = sum(df1$COLOR %in% COLOR)) %>% 
    filter(slr == max(slr))
```

**data.table**

```
setDT(df)
df[,slr := sum(df1$COLOR %in% COLOR),.(MODEL,MAKE)]
df = df[slr == max(slr)]
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
   YEAR MODEL   MAKE ORDERCODE  COLOR slr
1: 2001 LEXUS GS300h       YUK  BLACK   4
2: 2001 LEXUS GS300h       HNY   BLUE   4
3: 2002 LEXUS GS300h       ASF PURPLE   4
4: 2002 LEXUS GS300h       FAS  BROWN   4
5: 2002 LEXUS GS300h       YUI    RED   4
```

Comment: Actually sorry.. I realized I led you astray... the Make column is important.  It's the MODEL column that isn't.  My goal is to find the MAKE in table1 that is closest to table2.  SOrry about that.  I'll fix the above comment too

Comment: @Sheila I've updated the data.table solution Please check it is fine. Updating dplyr solution in a while.

Comment: Hi @YOLO, my desired output is just GS300h in this example (Make) not all LEXUS (Model).  I tried subbing MODEL or MAKE and did not get the desired output.

Comment: This works for the example, but would not work if there are duplicate colors for each `MODEL` + `MAKE` combination.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(MODEL, MAKE) %>%
  mutate(COLOR2 = ifelse(COLOR %in% df2$COLOR, COLOR, NA),
         count = n_distinct(COLOR2[!is.na(COLOR2)])) %>%
  filter(count == nrow(df2)) %>%
  select(-COLOR2, -count)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   MODEL, MAKE [1]
   YEAR MODEL   MAKE ORDERCODE  COLOR
  <int> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>
1  2001 LEXUS GS300h       YUK  BLACK
2  2001 LEXUS GS300h       HNY   BLUE
3  2002 LEXUS GS300h       ASF PURPLE
4  2002 LEXUS GS300h       FAS  BROWN
5  2002 LEXUS GS300h       YUI    RED
```